# Elements dissappearing in safari on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, safari

Ive made a simple project with html and jquery. It works great in all browsers except for safari on ipads. Since apple doesnt have a windows version of safari i cannot check if the error is explicitly for ipad but i think so.

The problem is the photoboxes wich get their width from the jquery, they dont appear at all on the ipad. Chromes developer tools device mode shows everything correctly and i have css queries that take care of smaller screens so its only the ipad thats the problem. I havent found any way to do a web debug on the ipad either. Its hard to give a code example due to i dont really know what the error is but i have a live demo you can check out. For you on ipads, its supposed to be photos before the winter background.

http://www.mj-bygg.se/ipad/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error on desktop Chrome on the first load. If I refresh, then the pictures load fine but on first visit to the link I only get the footer image (trees.)

On the first load, none of your jQuery heights/widths are being applied. No errors in the console and if I rerun the function it works as it should (without reloading the page.)

I suggest either pushing the script further down the page or using $(window).load(function() {} 
instead of
$(document).ready(function() {}

That is the only thing I can assume is wrong if it fails first time but works with the page being cached.